# JavaFX- CubeSystem3D Convert cubes to spheres

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

In netbeans, there is an option under samples called CubeSystem3D. I was wondering if there was a way to convert all of the cubes to spheres so I can eventually create a solar system type of thing. I can send the actual code if you are unable to retrieve it off netbeans because I can not put the code of this post as it says there will be too much code compared with text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below `Ellipse` class instead of `Cube` class in that neabeans sample code.

```
public class Ellipse extends Group {

    final Rotate rx = new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    final Rotate ry = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    final Rotate rz = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);

    public Ellipse(double size, Color color, double shade) {
        PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
        material.setDiffuseColor(color);
        material.setSpecularColor(Color.BLACK);

        getTransforms().addAll(rz, ry, rx);
        Sphere s = new Sphere(size);
        s.setMaterial(material);
        getChildren().addAll(s);
    }
}
```

> You will get something like this,

[image]